# switch screen automator script

Tags: applescript, fullscreen, osx-mavericks

i often find that my mac - who works with 2 screens in the office - not always remembers the screen where the app was closed. I also want to switch screens sometimes for apps - e.g. with launch bar - so i started searching and cominbing an apple script but it doesn't work properly.

if an app is full screen mode, the script just changes the canvas of the app - Safari page - and not the full app, so i decided to check, the status and do exit "fullscreen" and switch afterwards. This results in the problem, that the script exits full screen and on the second attempt, the screen is switched… im a novice so I don't know what to do anymore.

Working on Mavericks…

```
# by kg
# Version 1.0
# Date: Do. 20. März, 2014
# isFullscreen and toggleFullscreen from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215501/applescript-use-lion-fullscreen
set leftScreen to {-1440, 0}
set rightScreen to {0, 0}
set wasFullScreen to false




set myParam to isFullScreen()
if myParam is equal to true then
    toggleFullScreen()
    set wasFullScreen to true
end if
log "end if 1 - toggle fullscreen to little"
changepos()
if wasFullScreen is equal to true then
    toggleFullScreen()
end if
log "end if 2 - toggle fullscreen state to old"


on changepos()
    tell application "System Events"
        set theName to name of the first process whose frontmost is true
        set winPos to get position of first window of application process theName
        log "habe position von Fenster von " & theName & winPos
        --display dialog "na supa"
        if (item 1 of winPos is greater than or equal to "0") then
            set position of first window of application process theName to {-1440, 0}
            --display dialog "left screen"
        else
            set position of first window of application process theName to {0, 0}
            --display dialog "right screen"
        end if
    end tell
    --display dialog "aus"
    return true
end changepos

on isFullScreen()
    tell application "System Events"
        try
            tell front window of (first process whose frontmost is true)
                return get value of attribute "AXFullScreen"
            end tell
        end try
    end tell
    return false
end isFullScreen

on toggleFullScreen()
    set isFullScreenAfter to false
    tell application "System Events"
        try
            tell front window of (first process whose frontmost is true)
                set isFullScreen to get value of attribute "AXFullScreen"
                set isFullScreenAfter to not isFullScreen
                set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" to isFullScreenAfter
            end tell
        end try
    end tell
    return isFullScreenAfter
end toggleFullScreen
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I couldn't figure out a way in applescript, but I found an app called [BetterSnapTool](https://itunes.apple.com/at/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12) which is very neat. It can switch between screens and do a lot more for you!

Cheers.kg